# Mass Upload data from mobile handset (sqlite) to mysql server using PHP

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-asynctask

In my android app, the users need to go from door to door and insert some data via the mobile app. If internet is available at the time of recording the data, then the data is stored in the remote mysql server through a PHP API.

If internet is not available at the time of recording the data, then the data is stored in a sqlite DB in the mobile handset. At the end of the day, when the user comes back to his base, he connects his mobile handset to internet and clicks on a button provided in the app for uploading the sqlite data to the remote server via the PHP API. When the button is clicked, data is fetched from the sqlite DB through a cursor and the PHP API is called through an asynctask function within the cursor loop.

This approach works fine if I have 100-150 records to be updated. However, if the number of sqlite records is more the app crashes.

I understand that asynctask has limitations regarding number of concurrent tasks. However, I am unable to find a suitable alternate approach.

I am using Android Studio gradle 5.1.1

**Sample code that I am using:**

The following fetches all non updated data from the sqlite table (having the value of the 'up' column as 0). Checkremote is the function which calls the asynctask.

```
public void remoteUpdate(){
    tblBillSAP ed=new tblBillSAP();
    SQLiteDatabase db = pdb.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery =  "SELECT * FROM " +
            ed.Table+" WHERE up='0'";
    int i=0;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Updating...Please wait...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        do {
        
            String consno=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_consno));
            String dtc=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_MRU));
            String 
currentReadingDate=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_currentReadingDate));
            String load=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_load));
            String billNo=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_billNo));
            String billDate=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_billDate));
            String meterNo=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_meterNo));
            String mrNote=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_mrNote));
            String currentReading=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_currentReading));
            String unitsConsumed=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_unitsConsumed));
            String estimateFlag=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_estimateFlag));
            String 
 notedMeterReading=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_notedMeterReading));
            String pf=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_pf));
            String pfPenaltyRebate=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_pfPenaltyRebate));
            String deviceId=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_deviceId));
            String dueDate=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_dueDate));
            String netBill=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_netBill));
            String fc=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_fc));
            String ec=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_ec));
            String ad=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_ad));
            String ed1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_ed));
            String fpppa=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_fpppa));
            String adj=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_adj));
            String pArrear=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_pArrear));
            String oSurcharge=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_oSurcharge));
            String gSubsidy=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_gSubsidy));
            String cSurcharge=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_cSurcharge));
            String sv=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_sv));
            String scode=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_sCode));
            String sd=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_sd));
            String consName=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_consName));
            String consAddress=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_consAdress));
      String previousReadingDate=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_previousReadingDate));
            String noOfDays=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_noOfDays));
            String categoryName=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_categoryName));
            String phase=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_phase));
            String mf=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_mf));
            String previousReading=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_previousReading));
            String unitsBilled=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_unitsBilled));
            String slab1ec=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_slab1ec));
            String slab2ec=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_slab2ec));
            String slab3ec=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_slab3ec));
            String slab1et=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_slab1et));
            String slab2et=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_slab2et));
            String slab3et=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_slab3et));
            String slab1ut=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_slab1ut));
            String slab2ut=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_slab2ut));
            String slab3ut=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_slab3ut));
            String slabTotEc=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_slabTotEc));
            String mr=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_mr));
            String cd=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_cd));
            String user=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_user));
            String parent=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_parent));
            String mobNo=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_mobNo));
            String lat=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_lat));
            String longi=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_longi));
            String installationNo=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_installationNo));
            String MRD=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_MRD));
            String contractedDemand=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_contractedDemand));
            String pfFlag=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_pfFlag));
            String stateFlag=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_stateFlag));
            String md=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_md));
            String duesanjog=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_duesanjog));
            String noOfInstalment=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_noOfInstalment));
            String bid=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_id));
            String ecSubsidy=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_ecSubsidy));
            String fcSubsidy=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_fcSubsidy));
            String edSubsidy=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_edSubsidy));
            String netBillAfterRebate=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_netBillAfterRebate));
            String actualRebate=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_actualRebate));
            String fcActual=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_fcActual));
            String catfortable=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_catfortable));
            String billTime=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ed.KEY_billTime));
            billId=Integer.parseInt(bid);
            checkRemote(consno,dtc,currentReadingDate,load,billNo,billDate,meterNo,mrNote,currentReading,unitsConsumed,estimateFlag,notedMeterReading,pf,pfPenaltyRebate,deviceId,dueDate,netBill,fc,ec,ad,ed1,fpppa,adj,pArrear,oSurcharge,gSubsidy,cSurcharge,sv,scode,sd,consName,consAddress,previousReadingDate,noOfDays,catfortable,phase,mf,previousReading,unitsBilled,slab1ec,slab2ec,slab3ec,slab1et,slab2et,slab3et,slab1ut,slab2ut,slab3ut,slabTotEc,mr,cd,user,parent,bid,mobNo,lat,longi,installationNo,MRD,contractedDemand,pfFlag,stateFlag,md,duesanjog,noOfInstalment,ecSubsidy,fcSubsidy,edSubsidy,netBillAfterRebate,actualRebate,fcActual,billTime);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Updated data exists in portal!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}


public void checkRemote(String a1,String a2,String a3,String a4,String a5,String a6,String a7,String a8,String a9,String a10,String a11,String a12,String a13,String a14,String a15,String a16,String a17,String a18,String a19,String a20,String a21,String a22,String a23,String a24,String a25,String a26, String a27, String a28, String a29, String a30,String a31, String a32,String a33,String a34,String a35,String a36,String a37,String a38,String a39,String a40,String a41,String a42,String a43,String a44,String a45,String a46,String a47,String a48,String a49,String a50,String a51,String a52,String a53, String a54, String a55, String a56, String a57,String a58, String a59,String a60,String a61,String a62,String a63,String a64,String a65, String a66, String a67, String a68, String a69, String a70, String a71, String a72){
    new AsyncContract5().execute(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, a18, a19, a20, a21, a22, a23, a24, a25, a26, a27, a28, a29, a30, a31, a32, a33, a34, a35, a36, a37, a38, a39, a40, a41, a42, a43, a44, a45, a46, a47, a48, a49, a50, a51, a52, a53, a54, a55, a56, a57, a58, a59, a60,a61,a62,a63,a64,a65, a66, a67, a68, a69, a70, a71, a72);

}
```

Please help..

Comment: `I understand that asynctask has limitations regarding number of concurrent tasks.` ??? An async task is only one task. Why would you need more?

Comment: Please post your code in such a way that we dont have to scroll horizontally half an hour.

Comment: If your app crashes there will have been an exception. Look in the logcat to find it. Then report.

Comment: @blackapps, as you can see from my code, the asynctask is being called in a loop. So the case of concurrent execution happens for asynctask. The exception occurs because maximum limit of 138 concurrent tasks is violated. 

Hence, I am looking for an alternative way of achieving my objective

Comment: Use one async task for all. Or start the next one when the first is done. Or start only the next task after five seconds. Dont blindly start so many task at once. Makes no sense. You brought yourself into this trouble.

Comment: @blackapps, thanks for the suggestions..which I have already tried. But thanks anyway..